# VB.net tray icon creation

Tags: vb.net, system-tray

I am dynamically creating a NotifyIcon using the code below:

```
Dim traysystem As New NotifyIcon
```

Question being, how can I create a click event for that?

I've tried:

```
Private Sub traysystem_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  _
System.EventArgs) Handles traysystem.Click
    messagebox.show("test!")
End Sub
```

But yeah, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handles requires WithEvents in the DIM statement:

```
 Dim WithEvents traysystem As New NotifyIcon
```

The scope of this declaration isn't obvious from the snippet.  If it is a local variable then you have to use AddHandler and remove the Handles keyword:

```
    Dim traysystem As New NotifyIcon
    AddHandler traysystem.Click, AddressOf traysystem_click
```